# Could not read Sitecore configuration in console application

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am creating web api as follows:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
  //Get Products Prices 

    public string GetProductPrices(string ProductName)
    {
      //some method definition
    }
 }
```

I have defined webapiconfig as follows.

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Default",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "ProductVariations", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

When I try calling web api from url, it returns me error 400.

I am calling the above method as follows:

1) http://site.com/api/Products/apple-ipod-touch/GetProductPrices

2) http://site.com/api/Products/GetProductPrices/apple-ipod-touch

Please correct my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) for the beginning.

Either you have to create a route with `ProductName`, or you have to create a cotroller name with `Id` parameter input. You can't map `ProductName` route to `Id` input parameter.

PS: First way of requesting api is invalid. You have a route, where controller name has second position in url, it definetely can't be on third, it won't match to a predefined route.

If you modify the route:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{ProductName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "ProductVariations", ProductName = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

But better use id in your webapi url, this case url will be neater.

Comment: I changed as follows in webapiurl.

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Default",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{ProductName}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "GetProductPrices", ProductName = RouteParameter.Optional });

Comment: I modified as you said in the webapiconfig.